# Stripe user token issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, payment, stripe-payments

I'm following this guide (https://mikesabat.wordpress.com/2013/12/15/making-users-pay-building-a-site-with-strip-and-devise/) with no modifications other than changing the Stripe library to v2 instead of v1.

Basically, my issue is that the **stripe_card_token** field saves a value starting with *tok_BLAHBLAHBLAH*, whereas in the Stripe dashboard, each customer has a token like cus_BLAHBLAHBLAH.

My javascript that returns the stripe token and fills into a hidden field is:

```
handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
if status == 200
  console.log(response);
  $('#user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
  $('#new_user')[0].submit()
else
  $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
  $('#stripe_error').show()
  $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These tokens are actually two different things -- the `tok_XXX` value is a single-use card token, and the `cus_XXX` value is a customer id.

After your user enters their credit card information into your form, and Stripe returns a card token via javascript, you'll then submit that token to your server-side code.

Once your server-side code receives the card token, you'll then submit a Stripe API "create customer" call to Stripe, from your server (NOT from Javascript). This API call takes a card token as an input, and returns a permanent customer id as a response (among other things).

The customer id is the value that you'll save in your database, and you'll send it to Stripe when you need to make charges to the customer's credit card.

See the [Create Customer API call](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) for more information.